# JQuery UI Date Picker with Angularjs directive getting wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

My 2 Date Pickers bind with Angularjs directive. But i validate with java script.
after selecting date it return default date.

**Script**

```
<script>
    if (datefield.type != "date") { //if browser doesn't support input type="date", initialize date picker widget:
        jQuery(function ($) { //on document.ready
            $('#start_date').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                minDate: 0,
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    var date2 = $('#start_date').datepicker('getDate');
                    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
                    $('#end_date').datepicker('setDate', date2);
                    //sets minDate to start_date date + 1
                    $('#end_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate', date2);
                }
            });
            $('#end_date').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                onClose: function () {
                    var start_date = $('#start_date').datepicker('getDate');
                    console.log(start_date);
                    var end_date = $('#end_date').datepicker('getDate');
                    if (end_date <= start_date) {
                        var minDate = $('#end_date').datepicker('option', 'minDate');
                        $('#end_date').datepicker('setDate', minDate);
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    }
</script>
```

**Html Code**

```
<div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label name="lblOccup1"> Check in</label>
            <input type="date" id="start_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Check in" data-ng-model="departuredate"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label name="lblOccup1"> Check out</label>
            <input type="date" id="end_date" class="form-control" placeholder="Check Out" data-ng-model="returndate"/>
        </div>
 </div> 
 <div class="col-md-2">
    <a class="link_button2" ng-href="@Url.Action("Booking", "home")?Rooms={{rooms}}&Destination={{des}}&DepartureDate={{departuredate}}&ReturnDate={{returndate}}"> Search </a>
</div>
```

After press search button i get null value to mvc controller.

**Search Form**

[image]

**Controller** 
[image]

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: why you dont use ui-bootstrap date picker ?

Comment: @ThanhTùng I'm using jQuery UI Date Picker. i'll try bootstrap date picker.